# Regex to search pattern surrounded by a common pattern repetitively

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have following string.

```
$str = "abafghababa";
```

I want to search pattern aba and its count.

Expected output for count is 3

I was trying with `$count = () = $str =~ /aba/;`
But this is resulting as 2 which is correct. But i want to findout a way where it can result as 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to match `aba` that are overlapping you will need to use lookaheads which is zero width assertion.

You can use this rgex:

```
/(?=(aba))/g
```

And get the group count.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2dT0/1)

Comment: I think an explanation for OP and for further readers would be helpful what the regex exactly does

Comment: Actually it is pretty simple regex based on lookahead (zero width assertion) and I have written briefly about it. Besides linked demo has more details for this.